# Phaser 2 buttons are needed to work text? What's happening?

Tags: javascript, button, text, phaser-framework

I'm working on a dialogue system for my game. I have it almost finished, but I'm stuck on one weird bug. Here is the code for it in the update method. Assume everything with this in front of it was declared in the create method.

```js
    if ((this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.goodLamb) || this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.stiches)) && Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.keyT)) {
        this.talking = true;
    }

    if (this.talking == true){
        if (this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.goodLamb) || this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.stiches)) {
            if (this.has("spool") && this.has("needleOne") && this.has("needleTwo")){
                this.line1.setText('Good Lamb: Oh, thanks Peef! Now we can fix Stiches!');
                this.line2.setText('Peef: Glad to help. I know how painful rips are.');
            }
            else if (!(this.has("spool")) || !(this.has("needleOne")) || !(this.has("needleTwo"))) {
                this.line1.setText('Good Lamb: Help! Stiches ripped herself again! Can you get the sewing supplies?');
                this.line2.setText('Peef: Oh gosh! Sit tight Stiches. Ill be back soon!');
            }
        }

        if(this.keyA.isDown) {
            this.p1.setVelocityX(0);
        }
        else if(this.keyD.isDown) {
            this.p1.setVelocityX(0);
        }
        if(this.p1.body.touching.down && Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.keyW)) {
            this.p1.body.setVelocityY(0);
        }

        if ((this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.goodLamb) || this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.stiches)) && Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.keyT)){
            this.talking = false;
            this.line1.setText('');
            this.line2.setText('');
        }
    }
```

I admit this may be an outrageously overly complicated text system, but it's the only one I've gotten to work. When the player presses the talk button when touching an npc, the game checks for collision and sets the talking Boolean to true. If that Boolean is true, the game disables the player's movement and displays dialogue based on who the npc is and if they met the criteria for completing the associated quest, in this case gathering 2 needles and a spool of thread. For the player to continue, they have to press the talk button again, which turns the talking Boolean back to false, restores movement and makes the text disappear.

It's the last step that's not working. For some reason, when the player presses the talking button again, the talking Boolean doesn't change back and none of the associated actions happen.

The only solution I currently have is to change the button that makes the text disappear to a different button from the talking button. This lets things work as intended, but it's also an awkward button set up for the player.

Is there a solution, or am I just going to have to live with this issue?

If it helps, I'm using Phaser 3 in VSCode employing arcade physics.

Comment: I updated my answer with a shorter / more legible code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

No 1 Button is enough. What is happening, is hard to say, because your code is pretty complicated. In any case the **main** problem is that your `if/else` blocks are setup incorrect.

I cleaned it up and tried the `if/else`blocks in the correct order, so that they reflect, what you want to happen. Although it is hard to say since, your code snippet covers only a small part of your `update` function.

```js
if ((this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.goodLamb) || this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.stiches)) && Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.keyT)) {
    if(this.talking == false){
        this.talking = true;
        if (this.has("spool") && this.has("needleOne") && this.has("needleTwo")) {
            this.line1.setText('Good Lamb: Oh, thanks Peef! Now we can fix Stiches!');
            this.line2.setText('Peef: Glad to help. I know how painful rips are.');
        }
        else if (!(this.has("spool")) || !(this.has("needleOne")) || !(this.has("needleTwo"))) {
            this.line1.setText('Good Lamb: Help! Stiches ripped herself again! Can you get the sewing supplies?');
            this.line2.setText('Peef: Oh gosh! Sit tight Stiches. Ill be back soon!');
        }

        /* this velocity blocks seem strange, but if it works for you why not */
        if (this.keyA.isDown || this.keyD.isDown) {
            this.p1.setVelocityX(0);
        }

        if (this.p1.body.touching.down && Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.keyW)) {
            this.p1.body.setVelocityY(0);
        }

    } else {
        this.talking = false;
        this.line1.setText('');
        this.line2.setText('');
    }
    
}
```

Try to keep `if/else` nesting low, and try to group condition to avoid mistakes and performance issues *(for example: multiple calculations / collision checks)*

### Update / Improvement

Here the same code from above just more concise, and easier to understand / read

```js
/* default text values is empty string */
let textLine1 = '';
let textLine2 = '';

/* I put "Phaser.Input.Keyboard..." first, for performance reasons */
if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.keyT) && (this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.goodLamb) || this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.stiches))) {
    if(this.talking == false){
        let hasAllItems = this.has("spool") && this.has("needleOne") && this.has("needleTwo");
        if (hasAllItems) {
            textLine1 = 'Good Lamb: Oh, ...';
            textLine2 = 'Peef: Glad to help. ...';
        } else {
            textLine1 ='Good Lamb: Help! ...';
            textLine2 = 'Peef: Oh gosh! ...';
        }

        /* just set the velocity always to 0, no if/else is needed */
        this.p1.setVelocity(0);
    } 

    // toggles: true <=> false
    this.talking = !this.talking;

    /* set the text's object in one place, no matter the text */
    this.line1.setText(textLine1);
    this.line2.setText(textLine2);
}
```

Comment: I was able to get it working using a few pieces from your examples. (mostly using this.talking = !this.talking;)

Comment: I admit that this I've changed the code little, and barely used anything your displayed. 

The use of let textLine1 = '';
let textLine2 = '';

can off as unnecessary, and having the trigger to display lines be if(this.talking == false) just confused me. 

Since I used less than 10% of your example, should I still give you the check?

Comment: @EmptyStone you don't have to ask me each time. if you think my answer/work deserves a checkmark or/and an upvote, than go ahead. If you think it doesn't then by all mean don't give neither. The whole voteing / checkmark system is on the one hand a gamification, so that people collect points and help people, and on the other hand a signal to others, that the answer is helpful and/or solved the problem. It's your decision, how you want to play the game. In any case relax and have fun. :)